# N biggest values of dict with duplicates

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

For instance we have this dict:

```
scores={'L Messi':18, 'R Falcao':16, 'R Van Persie':14, 'F Torres':0, 'C Ronaldo':16}
```

So, i need to implement a function, which will print the first N best scores(biggest values). For this example if **n=3** it should print this:

```
L Messi 18
C Ronaldo 16
R Falcao 16
R Van Persie 14
```

Any suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and it's `.most_common()` method:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> scores={'L Messi':18, 'R Falcao':16, 'R Van Persie':14, 'F Torres':0, 'C Ronaldo':16}
>>> scores = Counter(scores)
>>> for name, score in scores.most_common(4):
...     print '{}: {}'.format(name, score)
... 
L Messi: 18
R Falcao: 16
C Ronaldo: 16
R Van Persie: 14
```

If you *have* to implement the `.most_common()` code yourself, at least [reference the `.most_common()` source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l453), which uses [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html).

To get the most common *values*, you can build on top of this:

```
def most_common_values(counter, count):
    values = set()
    most_common = iter(counter.most_common())
    while len(values) < count:
        key, value = next(most_common)
        values.add(value)
        yield key, value
```

For your example:

```
>>> for name, score in most_common_values(scores, 3):
...     print '{}: {}'.format(name, score)
... 
L Messi: 18
R Falcao: 16
C Ronaldo: 16
R Van Persie: 14
```

Comment: You used there 4 in argument for most_common, but number of duplicates is unknown.

Comment: @ratkke: That was *not* clear from your question; so you want to get the 3 most common *values*, with duplicates expanding as needed.

Comment: I'm confused.  The question said the biggest values, not the most common.  The OP liked the answer though, so I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: @VaughnCato: To a counter, the biggest values represent the most common elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = {'L Messi':18, 'R Falcao':16, 'R Van Persie':14, 'F Torres':0, 'C Ronaldo':16}
top_scores = sorted(set(scores.values()), reverse=True)[:3]
filtered = sorted([[e, scores[e]] for e in scores if scores[e] in top_scores], key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)
for n, s in filtered:
    print("%s: %s" % (n, s))
```